# Automatically fetch fresh PDF document when opening in new window

Tags: html, hyperlink, refresh, new-window, no-cache

I know that headers can ensure a page that is fetched is always fresh:  [How to control web page caching, across all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers)

But I just need to fetch a PDF in a new window.
I'm using the following code to fetch the PDF, but how can I make sure the PDF itself a fresh (non-cached version)?

```
<a href='/somepath/doc.pdf' id='pdf' target='_blank'>View PDF</a>
```

Because my application dynamically creates PDF documents all the time, I want the most recent one. Is it not possible to do this simply? Or do I need to write a PHP page dedicated for this or something?

Comment: What PDF-reader (browser-plugin?), OS and browser are you targeting?

Comment: Chrome, IE, Firefox. No PDF reader, just relying on the browser, regardless of OS. (PDF is platform-independent, and the browsers have their own way of handling PDFs, right?)

Comment: this might sound like a stupid solution, but could you not just a querystring to the URL, and each time use something random... like "/somepath/doc.pdf?blah=12345"

Comment: @SQLGuru: Your train of thought is the proper one. However, parameters are a bad idea [fingerprinting](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care) is a better way.